# Python newbie question - I can't figure out what my problem is exactly

Tags: python

I'm completely new to Python and I've been trying to make a fibonacci program with it.

```
def fib(n):
    print 'n =', n
    if n > 1:
        return n * fib(n - 1)
    else:
        print 'end of the line'
    return 1

n = raw_input('Input number: ')
int(n)
fib(n)
```

When I try to run this program, I get the following error after entering the number:

> Input number: 5
>
> n = 5
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "fibonacci.py", line 11, in
>
> ```
> fib(n)
> ```
>
> File "fibonacci.py", line 4, in fib
>
> ```
> return n * fib(n - 1)
> ```
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)
>   for -: 'str' and 'int'

If I run the interpreter and import just the function (without the code after it), supply the value for n and call the function with the value as the parameter, it works.

I tried converting the input to int since I thought it was a string problem but no dice. I don't really know where I went wrong so if you could please shed some light on the subject, it'll be much appreciated.

I'd love to change the problem title to something specific but I don't really know what the problem is.

Comment: Please provide meaningful title for the question next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that raw_input is providing a string, not an integer. Can I suggest just putting the integer value into `n` in the first place:

```
n = int(raw_input('Input numver: '))
fib(n)
```

Avoid `n = int(n)` as in a longer section of code it would be unclear when you came back to it what type `n` is, and you have no need for the original string value.

The deeper understanding you need is that Python is strongly typed - it cares what type everything is, but it is also dynamically typed, so `n` could change from holding a string value to holding an integer value. But Python is still keeping track of what is held, so when you put the return value of `raw_input` into `n`, Python knows it is a string, so multiplying that string by a number makes no sense and returns an error.

Comment: I'll be accepting this as the answer. I like the explanation you made along with your answer.

Answer (score 6):

raw_input() returns a string, as you've surmised. However, int(n) doesn't change the value of n to an integer, instead it returns the converted value. You need to do:

```
n = int(n)
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

Just make a small change :

```
n = raw_input('Input number: ')
n = int(n)
fib(n)
```

The int conversion takes a string which you obtained from raw_input and returns a integer. You need to pass the return value to fib(..).

```
int_obj = int(str_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `int(raw_input('Input number: '))` instead of `raw_input('Input number: ')`